# Text box value not updating properly according to the change in spinner value (and i have tried most of the methods in stackoverflow)

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

There is a spinner in `MainActivity` and 1 text box in `fragment`. My task is to change the value of text box according to the recently selected spinner value. My code works well, but the textbox changes its state only after 2 swipes. I don't know why this lagging happening. Help me out (**Before downvoting kindly say some solutions**)

Here is my code in main activity

```
spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
final ArrayAdapter&lt;String&gt; dataAdapter1 = new ArrayAdapter&lt;&gt;(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,array2);
dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter1);
spinner.invalidate();

spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView&lt;?&gt; parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        //dataAdapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"well",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        String pos = (String) spinner.getSelectedItem();
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("Mode", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = sharedPref.edit();
        prefEditor.putString("userChoicemode", pos);
        prefEditor.commit();
    }
    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView&lt;?&gt; parent) {
    }
});
```

My fragment code :

```
final TextView modeselect = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pass);

final SharedPreferences sharedPref = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("Mode", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
String get = sharedPref.getString("userChoicemode",selected);

modeselect.setText("" + get);
```

Comment: On `spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener` rewrite in `TextView`

Comment: this question is duplicate- https://stackoverflow.com/q/46153887/7230266

Comment: @shshwat there is no answer there.i have tried all those moethods in that duplicate

Comment: @dipali  kindly add ur comment as answer with code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to dynamically change the text box value according to the recently selected spinner value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46153887/how-to-dynamically-change-the-text-box-value-according-to-the-recently-selected)

Comment: @ShashwatGupta bro i have tried all those methods in that question already....its different

Comment: final TextView modeselect = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pass);

final SharedPreferences sharedPref = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("Mode", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
String get = sharedPref.getString("userChoicemode",selected);

modeselect.setText("" + get); put this code in setUserVisibleHint() override method of your fragment

Comment: there findviewbyid doesnt works  bro

Comment: `ArrayAdapter&lt;String&gt` is not valid code

Comment: It shows "Methods doesnot override from it super class"   bro

Comment: can you edit my code and post as your answer ??? @ShashwatGupta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In your fragment**

```
 @Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    try {
        if (isVisibleToUser) {
            final TextView modeselect = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pass);

final SharedPreferences sharedPref = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("Mode", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
String get = sharedPref.getString("userChoicemode",selected);

modeselect.setText("" + get);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
}
```

just add this override method into your fragment and put the value of selected spinner item in text view of fragment in this method. your inflated view should be declared globally

Comment: but one more problem bro...it changes only on swiping.i want to change my textbox value immediately after i change the spinner value

Comment: just put the code that sets value to your text view in a method and from your activity when on item selected call that method                                        ExampleFragment fragment = (ExampleFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.example_fragment);
fragment.<specific_function_name>();