# how to call method form inside fragment holded by view pager using interface?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-viewpager2

on my app I have a button in the mainActivity and viewPager2 with some fragments where each fragment has textsViews that must be field with information.
I want to check if the fields are filled when I click on the button " the activity button"
I'm trying to use  interfaces to fire the click event inside the fragment  but I don't know how

I tried this answer [Dynamically updating a fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37759734/dynamically-updating-a-fragment/37761276#37761276)  but it doesn't fit my problem

Comment: Can you please post your code.

Comment: @ pepperlove i didn't figure it out yet I tried the answer mentioned in the question